# How to enable html tags in tinymce editor?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have a problem with tags like paragraph in editor.

When I write in visual editor and put enter i see in code paragraph but when i save post nothing happens. No  breakline no paragraph nothing.

When i Use firebug to look inside a code on visual site I see tags, when i change to HTML version, code is clean.

I dont know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something of this kind might help:

```
// for your tinyMCE init function
tinyMCE.init({
theme : "advanced",
mode : "exact",
elements : "editorContent",
width : "565",
height : "200",
extended_valid_elements : "input[name|value|size|class|onclick|type],iframe[name|src|framespacing|border|frameborder|scrolling|title|height|width]"
});
```

Hope it helps